# What's the difference between fishing and diving?

Tags: story-of-seasons

So after you get a fishing pole you no longer *need* to go diving in the river like a maniac, or so I thought.

It seems like both methods get pretty much the same "loot table" with slight variants (fishing seems to be able to get larger fish), but it also takes longer than diving.

Which method is better, as in more rare *materials* obtained (don't really care too much about fish).

Comment: I haven't gotten the fishing rod yet, but I think diving may give you more influence over what you get. For example minerals are only found in certain places when diving, so if you're going after a specific mineral you might have better luck with diving. Also while the old fishing rod you get initially might be getting you significantly different stuff, it's possible that upgrading it might give access to better "loot tables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fishing by diving will only give 1/2 - 1 star fish, it can also only be done a few times per area. It does seem to get slightly more objects, though.

Fishing while using the rod can acquire fish/objects in the same spot indefinitely (well as long as you have stamina/time) and can get all star qualities (improved with fishing rank and rod type). You can also use various baits to alter how the fishing works.

- Normal Bait makes fish bite slightly more often
- Refined Bait makes fish bite more often
- King Bait makes caught fish bigger (useful for trophy unlocking and contests)
- Magic Bait increases the quality of fish and causes more rare catches

There are some things the rod does not catch, though, like clams.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about fishing, but I know that certain types of fish can only be caught while fishing. Another thing to remember is that the bait that you use affects your fish bite rate, star quality, and size.
Also, does anyone have any Or call it come, that mineral I need eight